# VSCode with Vue CTRL+Click go to definition not working inside HTML from vue file

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with all Vue extensions needed (including Vetur, which should be responsible for go to definitions) and whenever i am in a `.vue` filetype, i cannot hit CTRL+Click to go to definion of a variable, as shown bellow.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

It says 'No definition found' and i really do not want to change the IDE. Any workarounds for this?
I also tried Vue Peek extension

Comment: Two years later, anyone found a solution to this yet?

Comment: Not using Vue daily anymore, but checked some projects and looks like still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you still seek help, please show whole component.

If your definition lives outside the same file as your component you are in, it depends on how you import the file.

If its part of a mixin or helper.
Are you importing using absolute or relative path can also affect this.

Also i can depend on what types of frameworks you use, since your imports can have alias pointing to specific folders. Which may or may not be readable for VScode since the alias is only known to the compiler.